# Optimize aggregate query mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to optimize a consult on mongoose. First my models go like this:

```
    var TrackSchema = new Schema({
        Car: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Car'
        },
        Imei: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        Latitude: {
            type: Number
        },
        Longitude: {
            type: Number
        }
    });

    var CarSchema = new Schema({
        Basis: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Basis'
        },
        Imei: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        }
    });

    var BasisSchema = new Schema({
        Fence: {
            type: Array,
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is to get the last registers from `Tracks` with distinct Imei from model `Car`. But also I need to get the Fence field from `Basis` that is associate with `Car`.

I alredy have the query, but I want to improve it because it take some time the get it.

```
    Track.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    'Imei': '$Imei',
                    'Car': '$Car',
                },
                Longitude : { $last: '$Longitude' },
                Latitude : { $last: '$Latitude' },
                Fecha: { $last: '$CreatedDate'}
            },
        },
        { 
            $lookup: {
                    from: 'cars', 
                    localField: '_id.Car', 
                    foreignField: '_id', 
                    as: 'unit'  
                }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$unit'
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'basis',
                localField: 'unit.Basis',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'geofence'
            }
        }
    ])
    .exec(function(error, results){

    });
```

Comment: So what is the "single question"? That actually is the format here. If you wondering if you are doing something wrong then any time you feel tempted to write *"Also,.."* means it was actually time to hit the ["Ask a new Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Your "query" as several `$lookup` stages, looking like relational modelling on a database not designed for relational modelling. Generally not wise. So are we talking about "performance" or "getting extra results in the query"? Because you get "one per question". Which is it?

Comment: @NeilLunn Well I want a better performance on the query, I know that I'm trying to do something as relational db. So that's why I'm asking hot to improve it.